# Is it possible to change the template_directory?

Tags: bloginfo

I've created a site on a localhost that is going to be migrated to a ssl server, with the scripts, css, images all coming from a CDN.

To call files in the site i'm using `bloginfo('template_directory');` is there a way to alter this to fit with the sites requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter [`template_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_directory_uri/):

```
<?php
add_filter( 'template_directory_uri', function( $template_dir_uri ){
    return str_replace( 'http://example.com', 'https://cdn.example.com', $template_dir_uri );
});
```

This will change URIs so they point at a CDN subdomain served via HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware of this filter, for anyone else interested in using this here is a reference link http://wpseek.com/hook/template_directory_uri/

Comment: I've added a link to the code reference where the hook is documented.