# How to redirect template_directory to subdomain relativ url?

Tags: filters, templates, directory, subdomains

I use subdomains with the same template  and I try to use [filter template_directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195902/is-it-possible-to-change-the-template-directory) to replace serverName by `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` but it doesn't work .

The default page is [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) and the user must choose one of three spaces "move.website.com", "visit.website.com", "live.website.com". For each three spaces I created a subdomain ! I want to use the same template for each subdomain.

For that I redirect each subdomain to the template.
Using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] with the if condition inside index.php I can choose which file or code to display in fonction of subdomain .
But now I must modify all links (bloginfo(template_directory)) to add subdomain  at the beginning to url.

The relative url used by `get_template_directory` is still the same as default using filter - the subdomain isn't added :

```php
add_filter( 'template_directory', function( $template_dir ){
    $subdomain = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    return str_replace( 'https://website.com', $subdomain , $template_dir_uri );
});
```

I should get https://subdomain.website.com

Comment: The example you linked is using `template_directory_uri`.

Comment: Yes I know but I have tested both because  template_directory_uri doesn't modify the url .
`add_filter( 'template_directory', function( $template_dir ){
$subdomain = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
return str_replace( 'https://website.com', $subdomain , $template_dir );});` and `add_filter( 'template_directory_uri', function( $template_dir_uri ){
$subdomain = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
return str_replace( 'https://website.com', $subdomain , $template_dir_uri );});` doesn't do anything .

Comment: Are you trying to change where the template is loaded from, or are you trying to change URLs _in_ the templates?

Comment: Your question jumps directly into what you're doing without giving much context, explaining why, or what you're trying to achieve by doing this. Can you edit your question to explain what the problem you're trying to solve is? Why do you want to do this? Where is that code located? The filter you're using has nothing to do with URLs so I'm unsure what your thinking is or intentions, and `get_template_directory` doesn't return a URL

Comment: I completed my question in the initial post. I thought I used badly the filter template_directory and I was only waiting for advice on the misuse of this function if that was my problem.
Jacob: I try to add the subdomain to the bloginfo(template_directory) . With $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] it could be possible .

Comment: Ok so the filter in your example has absolutely nothing to do with that. This is why it’s important to clearly explain your problem.

Comment: It's also unclear what you meant by "I use subdomains with the same template" do you actually mean theme? A template is a PHP file loaded by WordPress, it doesn't have a URL. I'm going to make a guess, are you trying to make all the assets in your theme load from the same subdomain?

Comment: Yes I mean Theme, sorry. You suppose well with one exception : I don't want to apply it to a single subdomain but to three plus the main domain www.website.com. If the user choose "move.website.com" from main domain , this subdomain use the same theme but using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] I can apply a php condition to display only element for one subdomain. Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: I think i found a solution, I test it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476267/14081202. Do you think the caveats is still current ( oblige to login again each time when user switch to each subdomain) ?

Comment: This [solution](stackoverflow.com/a/36476267/14081202)  is good but one problem appear :  ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM . This error display when I'm logged ( or any user logged) and when I switch between subdomain and domain. As it is describe in the link of the solution it seems that cookies of login use the domain and subdomain in the url. Do you any idea how I can resolve tis issue whithout reduce WP security. Thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution to cookies which unlogged user when he switch subdomain : define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'website.com'); in wp_config